# Hide material in Blender

Tags: 3d-view, particles

I'm working on a school assignment in Blender, I was following a Cycles tutorial to create a bear with fur (hair) on it. My problem is that since I applied that material, it takes minutes to change selection in object mode, even if I apply wireframe viewport, the fur lines remain there. Can I somehow hide it while I rig the character? Thank you in advance! [image: bear fur]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hair particles are added to your mesh object through the modifier system. You can enable/disable the effects of any modifier for viewport and rendering, the camera is for rendering and the eye is for the viewport.

[image]

For particle systems you can also adjust the visibility within the particle settings.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very very much, I was looking at material at the whole time, not the particle system. I owe you a beer. :)